# Password or username input twice when hitting enter with Angular forms

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making a simple username and password dialogue with Angular. I have a template:

```
<label class="welcome-content">Username:</label>
<input #userName type="text" id="txtLoginUsername" (keyup.enter)="loginUser(userName.value)"
                                                                     (blur)="loginUser(userName); loginUser.value='' ">
<label class="welcome-content">Password:</label>
<input #userPass type="password" id="txtLoginPassword" (keyup.enter)="loginPass(userPass.value)"
                                                                     (blur)="loginPass(userPass); loginPass.value='' ">
<button class="linkButton welcome-content"  id="lnkLogin" (click)="loginUser(userName.value); loginPass(userPass.value)">Login</button>
```

And a controller:

```
userName: string = null;
userPass: string = null;

loginUser(userName): void {
    this.userName = userName;
    console.log(this.userName);
  }

  loginPass(userPass): void {
    this.userPass = userPass;
    console.log(this.userPass);
  }
```

Thing work fines when I click the button, but when I press enter in the user field I get the username output twice, and the same thing for the password if I hit enter in the password field. How do I make it so the values are only input once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code here:

```
<input #userName type="text" id="txtLoginUsername" 
     (keyup.enter)="loginUser(userName.value)"
     (blur)="loginUser(userName); loginUser.value='' ">
```

In looking just at the provided code, I would assume you really only want to log the user in when they click the Login button. So the `loginUser` method should really be remove from BOTH input boxes.

```
<label class="welcome-content">Username:</label>
<input #userName type="text" id="txtLoginUsername" >
<label class="welcome-content">Password:</label>
<input #userPass type="password" id="txtLoginPassword">
```

Comment: Then why does https://angular.io/guide/user-input tell me to put both in?? :/ I thought I needed blur for when there's no input in the field, so I don't get blank values? I really wanted them to be able to input by pressing enter too, it possible.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: So how is the flow supposed to work? The user should not be able to put in just a username and then log in, correct? They need to put in *both* the username and password? So how is the enter/blur supposed to flow in this case?

Comment: Oh! I just noticed! Yes, I changed it so only the password field allows input with the enter key but it still doubles on the password.

Comment: I spent some more time with the doc example and it does *not* look like the Enter key moves the user out of the field and hence does *not* generate the blur after entry. Is that what you are seeing in your application? Or does the Enter key move the user out of the field?

Comment: I changed it to your answer and it allows input on enter anyway. It seems the keyup command is not necessary at all in my case. Thanks for your assistance. I haven't tested for empty input but I can account for that in the controller anyway.